# Passing a parameter that is not an attribute of a model from edit to update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am using a form_for method in a form that gets rendered by the edit action.  I want to pass a parameter to the update action.  I am using hidden_field to do that with parameters already, but these are all being saved to the model upon update.  What if I want to pass a parameter that is not an attribute of the model.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't link the hidden field to the form variable:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :name, val %>
```